# Generic and Inheritance in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance

I have a generic class `Field[T]`. Now, I want to created and child class extends `Field[T]` with one more parameters. But I got compile error

```
class Field[T](val name: String, val label: String, val required: Boolean, val dataType: DataType[T])

class FK[T](override val name: String, override val label: String, override val required: Boolean, override val dataType: DataType[T], val ref: Type) extends Field[T]
```

Maybe I don't really understand Scala inheritance and generic. Please help me correct `FK` class.

Comment: 1) Too many undefined symbols, not [mcve] 2) You don't invoke `Field`s constructor anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be more specific as to what is being inherited.

```
... extends Field[T](name,label,required,dataType)
```

Comment: @khacsinhcs Please upvote or accept the answer as a way to say thank you. Your comment is likely to be deleted, comments like this are not expected here.